# Java Webdriver TestNG: Returning ArrayList index

Tags: java, pdf, selenium

I want to get pdf of test cases for which I have the below code.

**Base Class:**

```
package com.seleniummaster.testresultpdfproject;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ArrayList1 {

    public WebDriver driver;
    private String r1 = "test cleared";
    private String r2 = "test cleared2";
    private String r3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public ArrayList1() {

        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(r1);
        list.add(r2);
        list.add("Test Ended" +r3);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList(int pos) {
        return list;
    }
}
```

**PDF Class:**

```
public class PdfUtility {

    public void WriteTestResultToPdfFile(String fileName,List<String> testCase) 
    throws IOException, COSVisitorException
    {
      try
      { some code}
    }
}
```

**Test Case Class:**

```
public class Testpdf {

    public WebDriver driver;
    private ArrayList1 arraylist2;

    @Test
    public void testclass {

        Assert.something...

        arraylist2.getList(0);


        @AfterSuite
        public void tearDown() throws Exception { 

            PdfUtility pdfUtility=new PdfUtility();
           //add time stamp to the resultList
           arraylist2.getList(3);

          for (int i = 0; i < this.arraylist2.size(); i++) {
              /*
              want to store indexes used in this class like [0] and [3] 
              in some variables to use in WriteTestResultToPdfFile method.
              */
          }

         //write the test result pdf file with file name TestResult
         pdfUtility.WriteTestResultToPdfFile("TestResult.pdf", arraylist2());
         driver.quit();
```

In the Test Case class, I mentioned pdfUtility.WriteTestResultToPdfFile("TestResult.pdf", arraylist2()); which should create pdf containing the arrayList indexes used by this class **arraylist2.getList(3);** and arraylist2.getList(0);

Currently, it generates pdf but return all the indexes from Base class.
Please help me to create pdf with the indexes used in Test Case class only. I have quoted the areas in Test Case class where I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using parameter type as `List<String>` in  PdfUtility.WriteTestResultToPdfFile and passing ArrayList1 from TestCase class.

You can try the below code to get the list of indexes used in TestCase class. Made minor changes to Base Class and Test Class;

In **Base Class,** change the `getList` method as follows;

```
public String getList(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos);
}
```

Change **TestCase class** as

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testpdf {

   public WebDriver driver;
   private ArrayList1 arraylist2 = new ArrayList1();
   List<String> listTestClassIndexes = new ArrayList<String>();
   PdfUtility pdfUtility = new PdfUtility();

   @Test
   public void testclass() {
      listTestClassIndexes.add(arraylist2.getList(0));
   }

   @AfterSuite
   public void tearDown() throws Exception {
      // add time stamp to the resultList
      listTestClassIndexes.add(arraylist2.getList(2));

      // write the test result pdf file with file name TestResult
      pdfUtility.WriteTestResultToPdfFile("TestResult.pdf",
            listTestClassIndexes);
      driver.quit();
    }
}
```